# Related to pointers in C language

Tags: c, pointers

Assume that float takes 4 bytes, predict the output of following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    float arr[5] = {12.5, 10.0, 13.5, 90.5, 0.5};
    float *ptr1 = &arr[0];
    float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
 
    printf("%f ", *ptr2);
    printf("%d", ptr2 - ptr1);
 
   return 0;
}
```

My query is, I am not getting why the output for 2nd printf statement is 3 and not 12?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why would it be anything else? It's effectively equivalent to  `x + 3 - x`

Comment: Note that adding an integer to a pointer actually adds that many _units_. `x + 3` will increase `x` by `3 * typeof(float)`. Similarly, subtracting two pointers results in the number of _units_ by which they differ. Otherwise `arr[1]` would not be very useful. `arr[1]` is equivalent to `*(arr + 1)`, which would be garbage if the resultant pointer is only changed by one byte; it needs to be changed by one _unit_ (i.e. 4 bytes further, if dealing with 4-byte floats).

Comment: This homework assignment tries to make sure you understand "pointer arithmetic". On a side note: in the `printf`, you should not use "%d" for that. I leave it up to you (as part of your homework) to look up the correct formatting symbols to use.

Comment: Unrelated, `ptr2 - ptr1` is a `ptrdiff_t` result, and should use `%td` for the `printf` format specifier.

Comment: You can get 12 if you try explicit conversion to regular numerical values: `printf("%ld", (long) ptr2 - (long) ptr1);` (no real point in doing that, though. This is for demo purposes only)